# Sending characters A to D as part of DTMF tone using Twilio

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, dtmf

I have a question related to sending DTMF tones using Twilio.

I am able to send the number 0 to 9 and characters # and * as DTMF Tones using sendDigits option given in the below URL. https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/number#attributes-sendDigits

I have a need to send the characters A to D (A, B, C, D) as DTMF Tones.

Let me know, if there is a way to do that using Twilio.

Appreciate your help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

REST API spits out this error when I tried:

```
Unable to create record: Invalid sendDigits: 123abcd'
```

So I would think your only option is to create audio files of the DTMF for A,B,C and D and use them in conjunction with the play verb in your TwiML

Comment: Twilio developer evangelist here. The documentation lists [the allowed values of `sendDigits` as any digit](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/number#attributes), so A-D are not supported. I agree that creating audio files and playing them yourself is the best solution here.